# Array last inserted/deleted item

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How can I get the last inserted/deleted item from an array?

Is there any such built-in property?

I would be inserting/deleting using indices so `array.last` is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such built-in property. An array doesn't keep any history of the specific operations that resulted in its value. You must track it yourself if you need it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently doing this using `willSet` but was just curious if there was another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a variable and update it every time you insert/delete.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get the last object of the `array` you can use the count of that `array`.

if i have a `array` named `integerArray` i have inserted some objects than to get the last object .

```
int LastObject=[integerArray objectAtIndex:integerArray.count -1]intValue];
```

Comment: He's asking about Swift but your answer is Objective-C. Also he said he doesn't want the last object as in the object at the highest index. He wants the object that was most recently inserted or deleted (anywhere in the array).